# Powershell script scheduled using Task scheduler doesn't run...script runs fine

Tags: windows, powershell

I am using windows 8.
I have the following script file (that spits our all services to a CSV file). When I run this as follows from powershell editor, it works fine.

```
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\Powershell\SchedulingaScript.ps1
```

When I schedule this script from windows task scheduler it won't kick off.
I have "Unrestricted" execution policy set on that session. Following is the code in the script file and 2 images are the setting on the task scheduler.

```
  #Trying out scheduling powershell scripts

  Get-Service | Export-CSV "C:\ExportingServicestoaCSVFile.CSV"
```

[image: Actions]

[image: Trigger]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the -file Parameter. Simply enter powershell -? and you will see all possible options to launch powershell.

Hope this helps -tom

Comment: I tried with -File also. It runs fine at Powershell prompt. But not from Windows task scheduler

Comment: Simply put "powershell.exe" in the Program/Script field (without path). If this doesn´t help try to start the script from a cmd prompt starting with powershell.exe and appending the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In the Edit Action dialog Program box simply put `PowerShell`. In Arguments put `-file "C:\sciptlocation\scriptname.ps1"`